# $.ajax() call success handler datatype=text

Tags: ajax, comparison-operators

I have a simple ajax call that is returning a text string correctly from the server, and I want to compare the response in the success handler, in this case if data == "Yes", do something, however I can't seem to make the comparison operator work. Not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

Server side:

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) {
    $message .= "Yes";
}
echo $message;
```

jQuery:

```
dataType: "text",
success: function(data, success) {
   console.log(data, success); //Yes
   console.log(typeof(data));  // string
   var response = data;

   if(response == "Yes") {
      $('.slideout').animate({width:'0%'}, function() {
         $('.slideout').css({'display':'none'});
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was returning more data from the serve than I was expecting, that is why the comparison operator did not return as True.